# Elasticsearch how to set different value with different scores for the same filed?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have different type_id in an ES index , and want to give different value type_id different scores to make some type search result rank is higher .
My query is

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"terms":{"type_id":[9,10]}}
            ],
            "should":[
                {"match":{ "display_name":{"query":"keyword","boost":10}}},
                {"match":{ "description":{"query":"keyword","boost":2}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make `type_id` 9 match scores is higher than `type_id` 10 when  `display_name` and `description` is same .

Please guide me in this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: currently you have given example of 9 and 10 but let consider you have 3 values like 8, 9 and 10 then do you want to give more score to 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your queries like below and use boost to give more weightage to certain ids.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "type_id": {
                    "value": 9,
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "type_id": {
                    "value": 10,
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1, 
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "display_name": {
                    "query": "keyword",
                    "boost": 10
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "description": {
                    "query": "keyword",
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: For query in comment , you can use [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type_id": {
                        "value": 9
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "display_name": {
                        "query": "keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "description": {
                        "query": "keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "boost": "5"
          }
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type_id": {
                        "value": 10
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "display_name": {
                        "query": "keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "description": {
                        "query": "keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "boost": "4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's help me a lot .Btw, I have another further question . If I want every type's `display_name` and `description` are also different `boost`, there is any good query method ?

Comment: @xrui I have updated the answer for your above query.

Comment: can I do it like this
`{"query":{"bool":{"minimum_should_match":1,"should":[{"bool":{"must":{"term":{"type_id":{"value":9,"boost":2}}},"should":[{"match":{"display_name":{"query":"keyword","boost":10}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"keyword","boost":2}}}],"minimum_should_match":1}},{"bool":{"must":{"term":{"type_id":{"value":10,"boost":1}}},"should":[{"match":{"display_name":{"query":"keyword","boost":20}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"keyword","boost":5}}}],"minimum_should_match":1}}]}}}`
can expend it in json parse .

Comment: I have 100+ types . There is any problem about request body is too long, or es query parse has pressure ...

Comment: @xrui above is fine. Though I believe that function score will allow you to assign weight at group level. In terms of performance both will be same. You need to choose based on your requirement. To  answer second part, performance will decrease with size of query , as your filtering and parsing more data. You need to try this out to check if it is within your permissible limit